# Linux alternative to "readlink -e" for nonexistent files

Tags: readlink

On Windows, I often create a full path to a nonexistent file so that I can provide it to file-saving dialogue boxes, thus telling the host application where to save a file.  Using Cygwin, this is done as:

```
cygpath -au Some/Relative/Path.blah # For Cygwin apps
cygpath -aw Some/Relative/Path.blah # For Windows apps
```

I often pipe the resulting full path to Cygwin's `putclip` so that I can paste it into the file-saving dialogue box of the app in question.  More precisely, I pipe it to my own function `putclp` (no "i"), which removes the terminating carriage return.

The closest counterpart that I have found for Linux is

```
readlink -e Some/Relative/Path.blah
```

I pipe this to `xsel -ip` for the X-windows primary clipboard or `xsel -ib` for the more modern Windows-like clipboard in Ubuntu.

Unfortunately, `readlink -e` only returns a path to an *existing* file.  I often need to create a full path for a non-existent file because I'm telling an app where to create the file.

Is there a counterpart to `cygpath`/`readlink` that can create full paths to non-existent files based on a specified relative path?

If we assume that the desired command is called `GetFullPath`, here is an example of the desired functionality:

```
GetFullPath Relative/Path/To/Nonexistent/File
```

The result on standard out would be `/The/Full/Path/To/Nonexistent/File`.

Comment: Maybe `readlink -e Some/Relative|sed 's#$#/Path.blah#'`? Could be combined with `dirname` and `basename` or pattern removal like `${variable##pattern}`

Comment: @Bodo: I did think about that, though I was more thinking of directly editing the captured folder path using vi behaviour from the command line (specified via ~/.inputrc).  Whenever I use sed, I find myself fiddling with the expression a few times to get it right.  It's a good idea.  Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details how exactly you want to use this. You could create a script or shell function that splits the path into directory and file name, calls `readlink` and appends the file name.

Comment: Are you looking for `readlink -m`?

Comment: @Bodo: I added an example of the sought functionality to the posted question.

Comment: @muru: That's it!  Thanks!  And after re-reading `readlink --help`, it should have been obvious.  I get confused when I read the "help", not because of the information that is easily understandable, but because my understanding gets easily derailed by words like "canonicalize".  I know what it means in general, but it seems to take on a mystic aura in a Linux context.  *Did you want to post that as the answer?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
realpath -m Some/Relative/Path.blah
```

would suffice – no need to resolve symbolic links on Linux, there is literally no usage difference between paths that involve links and those that don't. All the operations you can do on the latter also work on the former. A save dialog doesn't mind!

The same `-m` option also works for `readlink -e Some/Relative/Path.blah`, should you, for some rather strange reason, really care about not having symlinks in your save dialog!

Comment: Muller:  Thanks!  That's it!  User *muru* suggested the same in the comments to the original question.  I will use `readlink -m` in all cases now, since I've never encountered a situation in which I would want to do something different depending on whether the file exists.  The save dialogue box will ask for confirmation if the file exists.

Comment: @user2153235 hm @muru suggests `readlink`, I recommend `realpath`.

Comment: Oops.  Sorry.  Just had cataract surgery, so reading is hard.  Multiplies the time needed to read anything several fold, and text composition is rife with corrective activity.  Both work on my system.  And an addendum to my previous comment, if I'm going to ignore whether a file exists with `readlink`, I migjht as well use `readlink -f`.  Something I ran into while Googling the difference with `realpath`.

Comment: @user2153235 All the best for your eye(s) then!

Comment: Oops.  I made a mistake.  I tested `readlink -f` on a non-symlink file and a non-existent file, then concluded that it works for both and it should be my go-to "pattern".  But the help says that it follows links.  If one doesn't want that, then `readlink -m` and `realpath -m` will return a full path regardless of the file provided exists.